# How can I implement the getBit and setBit methods?

Tags: c#, bit

I'm trying to create my own BitArray class. How do I change the desired bit of a byte?

```
public class MyBitArray
{
    byte[] bytes;

    public MyBitArray(long limit, bool defaultValue = false)
    {
        long byteCount = (limit >> 3) + 1;
        bytes = new byte[byteCount];
        for(long i = 0; i < byteCount; i++)
        {
           bytes[i] = (defaultValue == true ? (byte)0xFF : (byte)0x00);
        }
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public bool this[long index]
    {
        get
        {
            return getValue(index);
        }
        set
        {
            setValue(index, value);
        }
    }

    bool getValue(long index)
    {
        long byteIndex = (index & 7) == 0 ? ((index >> 3) - 1) : index >> 3;
        byte bitIndex = (byte)(index % 8);

        return getBit(bytes[byteIndex], bitIndex);
    }

    void setValue(long index, bool value)
    {
       long byteIndex = (index & 7) == 0 ? (index >> 3) - 1 : index >> 3;
       byte bitIndex = (byte)(index % 8);

       bytes[byteIndex] = setBit(bytes[byteIndex], bitIndex, value);
    }

    bool getBit(byte byt, byte index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index > 7)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        return ?? // change bit and then return bool value if 0 false else true
    }



    byte setBit(byte byt, byte index, bool value)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index > 7)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        return ?? // change bit and then return changed byte
    }

    private long limit;
    public long Limit { get { return limit; } }
}
```

How can I get a working version of the `getBit` and `setBit` methods of the class I created? I want the code to run fast.

Answer (score 0):

Using bit masking:

```
    bool getBit(byte byt, byte index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index > 7)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        return (byt & (1 << index)) >> index;
    }



    byte setBit(byte byt, byte index, bool value)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index > 7)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        return (byt & ~(1 << index)) + (value ? 1 << index : 0);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

For clarity, would it be wise to use a two-dimensional byte array of 2048 elements for index values in the range 0 - 7 for each value of the byte previously prepared for performance?

Comment: Honestly, i don't know. Considering all the operations I used run in constant time, i don't think you'd get much performance gain from pre-calculating the results and storing them into a lookup table. That might actually be even slower, since you'd have to read it from memory.